# Api Windows c# handler de ventana

Tags: c#, api, net

tengo una aplicación que tiene dos formularios (usuario y contraseña), y quisiera diseñar una aplicación que logease en esa otra aplicación automáticamente.

Lo he hecho con SendKeys y funciona bastante bien, el problema está en que si el usuario mueve la ventana, o hace click fuera de otro formulario, los datos evidentemente se pasan ahí.

He estado leyendo sobre que alternativas existen, la Api de windows y controlar la ventana del proceso de la aplicación.

¿Podría alguien orientarme poniendome algún ejemplo de como se usaría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para automatización de Windows, ya sean UWP (Universal Windows Platform Application) o el legendario Winforms Win32 (llamado Classic Windows Application) puedes probar [WinAppDriver - Windows Application Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)

**¿Qué es básicamente WinAppDriver?** Puedes automatizar UI de igual forma que se realiza por ejemplo en [Selenium Driver](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/). Es decir por código C# en este caso de tu necesidad, poder manipular la UI de la aplicación objetivo.

Mira el ejemplo para notepad

```
// Launch Notepad
DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");
appCapabilities.SetCapability("appArguments", @"MyTestFile.txt");
appCapabilities.SetCapability("appWorkingDir", @"C:\MyTestFolder\");
NotepadSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), appCapabilities);

// Use the session to control the app
NotepadSession.FindElementByClassName("Edit").SendKeys("This is some text");
```

Hay [varios ejemplos en el repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/C%23)

**Cómo ubicar los elementos del formulario? el Id?** Idem al inspector de las paginas tienes una herramienta Inspect.exe que viene en el Windows SDK

- [Inspect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinAuto/inspect-objects?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)

Un ejemplo de como buscar el nombre [aquí](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/automate-windows-desktop-apps-winappdriver/#tab-con-5)

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar o servir de guia

- [WinAppDriver - Windows Application Driver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)
- [UI Test Automation for Browsers and Apps Using the WebDriver Standard](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2016/P499?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5001478)
- [Automate Windows Desktop Apps with WebDriver- WinAppDriver](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/automate-windows-desktop-apps-winappdriver/)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score -1):

System.Diagnostics.Process[] ieProcs = Process.GetProcessesByName("fsx");
        if (ieProcs.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in ieProcs)
            {
                SwitchToThisWindow(p.Handle, true);
                p.Refresh();
                break;
            }
        }

Comment: -1. Edita tu post para que se entienda el código y sobretodo **explica** como funciona.